# INSERT INTO SQL php Function does not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have managed to write a php script that checks if a username already exists in the database and only adds a new user if it does not already exist.

This is my php script:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['forename']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $forename = $_POST['forename'];
    $username = $_POST['surname'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $result = $dbcon -> prepare($stmt);
    $result->bind_param('s', $username);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($username);

    if($result->fetch()){
        echo "Can't add new user as it already exists!";
    }
    else{
        $stmt_two = "INSERT INTO users (username, forename, surname, password) 
                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $result_two = $dbcon -> prepare($stmt_two);
        $result_two->bind_param('ssss', $username, $forename, $surname, $password);
        $result_two->execute();
        $result_two->close();
        echo json_encode("Success");
    }
}
?>
```

I believe the records are not being inserted or being inserted intermittently due to the fact that I have more than one prepared statement. If I just do the `INSERT INTO` statement on its' own with the `SELECT FROM` statement - the records are added almost instantly.

Why is this and what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Just to mention, you don't need to check if there is already a register of this username using PHP. You can set the username column with a UNIQUE constraint. The query will fail if they try to add the same username again. So your code will be simpler.

Comment: what do you mean _slowly_? how slow? i don't think this chunk of code can eat up too much resources, and just use either `COUNT()` or `->num_rows`, its just two prepared statements, won't take that much time, how long does it take to do these things in your environment anyway? 15-30 seconds?

Comment: @Ghost It doesn't even insert the values into the database :(. It works fine when I don't have the select statement. Maybe you can help - I am just trying to add a username IF and ONLY IF it does not exist. Could I not do it in one statement?

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz there you go, it doesn't work, not slow, those two things are different. just use `->num_rows > 0` by the way, `isset` can take multiple arguments, `isset(x, y, z, ...)`

Comment: @Ghost I still don't understand how to fix this error. If you don't mind, could you please edit my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as I have said in the comments, don't over complicate and just check the number of rows found. No need to fetch anything. You're just checking if that user exists anyway.

```
$stmt = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$result = $dbcon->prepare($stmt);
$result->bind_param('s', $username);
$result->execute();
$result->store_result();

if($result->num_rows() > 0) { // if it exists

} else {
    // make your insertions
}
```

And another note:

`isset` can take multiple arguments:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['forename'], $_POST['surname'], $_POST['password'])) {
    // and so on
}
```

Edit: Another flavor (using `COUNT()` of MySQL):

```
$stmt = "SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$result = $dbcon->prepare($stmt);
$result->bind_param('s', $username);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($count);
$result->fetch();

if($count > 0) { // exists

} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: PERFECT!!! It works - and therefore I have given you an upvote and the accepted answer. Could you please explain why my code was not working before if you don't mind

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz it doesn't make sense to fetch anything, much easier to check the number of rows yielded, and always don't forget to invoke `->store_result()` after execution.

Comment: Thanks, what does `->store_result()` mean and why do I need to invoke it? I also noticed you didn't `close()` the connection - is there any reason why? I'm just curious

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz doesn't really need a closure for that prepared statement, after all its done, your script is done. you'll need to use `->store_result()`, here's a pertinent topic on that http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: Thanks, this means a lot. I'm actually starting to like php! +1